# Null pointer exception in an if statement in JSP?

Tags: java, database, jsp

I have a JSP program that deducts stocks from a given user input. There are 3 branches available (Example b1, b2, and b3). A form will be given to the user that will ask for the item code, the branch to borrow from and the number of stocks to be borrowed. I am also connected to a database that will update my tables after deduction.

I have an if statement that compares the user's choice of branch to borrow from and the real branch to determine which query will be executed.

I get no errors until I go back to the update form which says I have a NullPointerException on my if statement. I've been trying to look for solutions but nothing seems to help me solve my problem.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me on this one. Here's my code for the if statement.

```
    if (strBranch.equals("Binangonan")) {
       ps_Binang.executeUpdate();
       ps_AUpdate.executeUpdate();
  }
    else if (strBranch.equalsIgnoreCase("Tanay")) {
       ps_Tanay.executeUpdate();
     ps_AUpdate.executeUpdate();
  }
```

Comment: There is a possibility that `strBranch`, `ps_Binang`,`ps_Tanay` or `ps_AUpdate` is `null`. Change to `"Binangonan".equals(strBranch)`/ `"Tanay".equals(strBranch)` can prevent the NPE from the `if()` statement where you are comparing the strings.

Comment: Could you also post your html page? Mayby something isn't submitted...

Comment: .. that is why one should always use [yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions#Advantage) (at least to avoid the NPE)

Comment: @NINCOMPOOP AHHHHH Thank you so much! I'm not having any more exceptions. How do I check if an input field is empty? I tried if(strItemCode.isEmpty()) but got an exception as well.

Comment: Have you tried `if (someString==null && someString.isEmpty())`?

Comment: @Morfic not yet, i'll try it! :)

Comment: @Christine small typo as I was originally checking it's not empty, correct form is `if (someString==null || someString.isEmpty())`